# Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-cli

I'm getting the below error when trying to execute below AZ Rest command.

```
az rest \
     --method GET \
     --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<object-id>"

Insufficient privileges to complete the operation
```

Below are the permissions which I have given

[image]

Do I need to add any other permissions?

I'm logged in using a Service Principal

Comment: if you havent created the app yourself, you would need application.readwrite.all permissions. @juunas answer still valid tho.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exclamation mark visible to the right of the screenshot, I think an administrator has not granted the application permission.
You'll need an Application Admin/Cloud Application Admin/Global Admin to come in to that tab and click Grant permissions.

When you are logged in using a service principal, only the permissions with type Application will apply.
Delegated permissions only apply when you sign in using the app + a user.